# How to save a drawable in a file to associate later the drawable with an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

My app is getting an app's logo this way:

```
Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example");
```

I want to save in a file the drawable. When I do that I get in the file, for example:

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@b247c45
```

From there I would like when I relaunch the app to read the file and associate the drawable to an ImageView.

So I read the file, I get in a String `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@b697a45` and from there do:

```
ImageView img;
img.setImageDrawable(Drawable icon);
```

But I'm lost here: how do I translate a String in a Drawable? I have the impression that I need to store in the file a resource id rather than a drawable?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to take a resource that you have that is saved in the app bundle and then re-save that image in the file system in order to present that in an `ImageView`?

Comment: Maybe I over complicate this. I could redo a context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example") each time but since I already have the drawable why I would not save the call.

Comment: All you need to do is use the app Icon from the `drawable` folder and set it to the `ImageView`:: `Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myIcon, null);`  Then use that drawable :: `img.setImageDrawable(icon);` -- Note: I used "myIcon"  as a place holder. You will need to find the drawable you want to use from your `drawable` folder. Good Luck!

Comment: I don't know about the app when I start so I'll recheck each time the app. Thanks for the useful help to clarify my mind ;)